# Adding two integer numbers from array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Imagine the following code:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@200, @100, nil];
    
    NSInteger n1 = (NSInteger)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger n2 = (NSInteger)[arr objectAtIndex:1];
    NSInteger r = n1 + n2;
    
    NSLog(@"n: %lid", r);
```

The result I am getting is: `-4309586476825365866d`, the expected one is: `300`.

I also tried to evaluate the individual expressions in debugger to check what I am getting when reading the values from the array, like this: `po (NSInteger)[arr objectAtIndex:0]`. This showed the correct number, yet when trying to sum them both: `po (NSInteger)[arr objectAtIndex:0] + (NSInteger)[arr objectAtIndex:0]`, an invalid result is generated.

Any ideas why? I am very new to Objective-C, so any source where I could get more info about the issue is appreciated.

Comment: The `NSArray` can only hold objects: namely `NSNumber`s. `-objectAtIndex:` returns the pointer to the number; casting it to an `NSInteger` isn't what you want to do. Instead, use `[[arr objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **cast** `NSNumber` to `NSInteger`. You have to call `integerValue`.

And for more than 10 years there is a more convenient array literal syntax as well as a more convenient index subscription syntax

```
NSArray *arr = @[@200, @100];

NSInteger n1 = [arr[0] integerValue];
NSInteger n2 = [arr[1] integerValue];
NSInteger r = n1 + n2;

NSLog(@"n: %ld", r);
```

And for the string format use either `i` or `d` but not both.